# Select YEAR from mysql (pagination)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with records dating from 2006 to present (and ongoing), all with datetime stamps

What is the smartest/easiest way to extract all YEARS only and make a pagination link for each year (dynamically)?
Like this: 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012

Isn't this too clumsy and uses too many resources for that simple task?:

```
@mysql_query("SELECT YEAR(date) AS yearonly FROM table GROUP BY yearonly");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your solution is OK.

Using `select distinct` is another possibility

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date) AS yearonly FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

more simple ways can be:

You can use `group_concat()` to get all at once

```
SELECT group_concat(YEAR(date),SEPARATOR '') AS years FROM table GROUP BY YEAR(date)
```

OR

```
SELECT distinct YEAR(date,4) AS yearonly FROM table
```

OR

```
SELECT distinct  LEFT(date,4) AS yearonly FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the right answer, just dont forget ORDER BY yearonly.
For best performance, if you have a large dataset, create an index on the date column.

Answer (score 1):

For efficiency over the other suggestions and to avoid a full table-scan on a million row table for no reason:

create a table with all years from 2006 to 2050 ( or whenever you want ). Maybe call it `years`? Then:

```
select *
  from `years`
 where `year` <= year(curdate())
```

Comment: Yes, this would normally be what I would do. But the table only has 100-200 records, so it's not so big, and I don't want to work with scanning each record and put the year in a seperate table. But thanx

Comment: @mowgli, why not do it then :-).